# Conflict with TestNG dependencies and conditionally skipping tests

Tags: testng

I am trying to implement TestNG dependency in my XML (where one block of ~50 tests is dependent on another block of ~30 tests passing), but running into an issue with the skip annotations that I've previously implemented. It seems that the dependency is triggered also when a test is skipped, not just when it fails. Is there a workaround for this? I want to ignore the skipped test result and continue running the dependent tests, and only invoke the dependency if a test has explicitly failed.

From TestNG documentation:

> Hard dependencies. All the methods you depend on must have run and
> succeeded for you to run. If at least one failure occurred in your
> dependencies, you will not be invoked and marked as a SKIP in the
> report.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, sort of. Adding the below code to the afterInvocation method will change the test result from SKIP to PASS. This allows the dependent tests to run, but hides any skipped tests from your test results. In our case, this was preferable. If there is a better solution that doesn't cover up skipped tests I'd be happy to hear it!

```
if (method.getTestMethod().getRetryAnalyzer() != null && Retry.getRetryCount() == 0) { // check if the method was skipped without retries (due to skip annotation)
        
        ITestContext tc = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext();

        tc.getSkippedTests().addResult(method.getTestResult(), Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getMethod());
        tc.getSkippedTests().getAllMethods().remove(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getMethod());

        SMAPLogger.Info("Test result: Test Skipped -- marking test as passed to avoid dependency issues");
        Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);

        tc.getPassedTests().addResult(method.getTestResult(), Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getMethod());
        tc.getPassedTests().getAllMethods().remove(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getMethod());
    }
```